# bash - dash case to camel case

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr, busybox

I wrote the following to convert something like `foo-bar-baz` to `FooBarBaz`

```
sed -r 's/^(.)|-(.)/\U\1\U\2/g'
```

(Feel free to correct the above if there is something wrong)

However, it does not work with busybox :(

I could cobble something together with `cut`, `for` loops, bash substrings, and `tr`, but there must be a good one liner using busybox version of sed, awk, whatever.  Thoughts?

Comment: If busybox doesn't understand `\U` (which is likely), then a sed solution can't work.

Comment: You might want to restrict the `(.)` to have it only match alphabetics, or even only lowercase alphabetics. Perhaps numbers too if that's permissible? `([a-z0-9])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file(data) is same as shown samples if yes then following `awk`(s) may help you here.

```
echo "foo-bar-baz" |
awk -F"-" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}} 1' OFS=""
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With use of `RS`, `FS` and `ORS` in `awk`.

```
echo "foo-bar-baz" | 
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";RS="-";ORS=""} {$0=toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)} 1'
```

Comment: Cool. I did not know you could control the IFS and OFS of awk.  That lets me get rid of the `tr` parts in my solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave, yes we could do much more than that too :) Also try to select an answer a correct answer(after sometime of your post) to close the thread completely, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: If you want classic camel case (=first letter lowercase), change `for(i=1` to `for(i=2`

Answer (score -1):

I found an awk script that upper cases the first letter of each word.  I use `tr` to convert the dashes to spaces, run the script I stole, then use `tr` to remove the spaces:

```
echo "foo-bar-baz" \
    | tr '-' ' ' \
    | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }}1' \
    | tr -d ' '
```

Note, this is only the 2nd `awk` script I wrote, so no guarantees

Still, there must be a better way . . .